# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in wordpress plugin error

Tags: wordpress

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /customers/1/2/3/websiteurl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/videonab/lib/plugin-classes/video.php on line 123,124,125

Code is (Line no 123,124,125)

```
   public static function seconds_to_time( $seconds ){
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600); /* line no 123 */
    $mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60);/* line no 124 */
    $secs = floor($seconds % 60);/* line no 125 */
    return array(
            'hours'     => $hours,
            'minutes'   => $mins,
            'seconds'   => $secs,
        );
}
```

Comment: make sure seconds are greater than zero?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check for `is_numeric` or `is_integer`, and convert it to `(int)` before manipulating for any type of calculation.

```
public static function seconds_to_time( $seconds ) {

    if( is_numeric( $seconds ) ) {

        $hours = floor( (int)$seconds / 3600);
        $mins  = floor(( (int)$seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
        $secs  = floor( (int)$seconds % 60);

        return array(
            'hours'     => $hours,
            'minutes'   => $mins,
            'seconds'   => $secs,
        );

    } else {

        return array();
    }
}
```

Hope this one helps :)